# Meteor and OIM integration

Tags: meteor, oracle-fusion-middleware

To secure the data, we use OIM in our organization.

Is there any way to integrate Meteor app with Oracle Identity Manager(OIM)??

Answer (score 1):

From what ive read here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/core.1111/e12036/oam.htm
it can use LDAP, so my answer would be to intergrate it with:
https://atmospherejs.com/package/accounts-ldap-profile

which allowes to authenticate users against a LDAP server.

if you are unfamilliar with atmosphere packages, please read: https://atmospherejs.com/docs/installing